# Solid Angle Integrals

Tags: integration, trigonometry, physics

I'm currently working on solving a solid angle calculation for my physics project. I'm trying to solve it computationally using python - but my coding skills are basic at best. I need some hints/tips on how to go about solving this equation which I obtained from a research paper - equation 9b on (http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0969804306002090/1-s2.0-S0969804306002090-main.pdf?_tid=7b61d61e-d162-11e4-9032-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1427118343_91eaa37dbd9242927e86c41952074750)

The integral is:

$$\int_{12.76}^{43.71}\text{arccos}\left(\frac{p^2 - r^2 + h^2\tan^2(x)}{2ph\tan(x)}\right)\sin(x)\; dx$$

with $h = 68,$ $r = 24.8$ and $p = 40.2$

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm getting an issue which is that at $x=17$, the numerator in the arccos is $\sim 57000$, and the denominator is $\sim 19000$, so the integrand is $\arccos(3)$ which is undefined.  Did I do this calculation right?

Comment: the limits of integration are in degrees, not radians - if that helps!

Comment: Got it!  I'll try again and let you know how to do it if I get a result.

Comment: The paper to which you link costs US $40.  Unless you are buying, no thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am only able to access it through my university for free!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer I assume that everything is in degrees, though of course that's just a matter of scaling.

When you want to do numerical computing in python there's two handy packages: numpy and scipy.  Using these, your computation takes only a few lines.  First define a function for your integrand:

```
def integrand(x):
  import numpy as np
  p = 40.2
  r = 24.8
  h = 68
  theta = np.pi * x / 180 
  numerator = p**2 - r**2 + (h**2) * np.tan(theta)**2
  denominator = 2*h*p*np.tan(theta)
  return (np.arccos(numerator/denominator) * 180/np.pi) * np.sin(theta)
```

This could have been written in fewer lines, I just found that this way was easier to debug.  Now to integrate, you simply run

```
from scipy import integrate
result = integrate.quad(integrand, 12.77, 43.7)
print(result)
```

I had to truncate the interval a tiny bit because at the endpoints the input to $\arccos$ evaluates to slightly over $1$ and this ruins the whole computation.

The answer I got was about $425.4391$, to about that much accuracy (though this is effected by the truncation I did, so don't trust that number too much!).

Comment: Thank you very much this helps a lot. Just a question on a line of your code:

***return (np.arccos(numerator/denominator) * 180/np.pi) * np.sin(theta)***

Do I need to include the 180/pi factor for arccos? I assume as we've defined theta to be in radians in the first place then it's not necessary.

Comment: The 180/np.pi factor here is because np.arccos gives you an answer in radians and if you prefer degrees that's what you would do.  But you're right, it's a scaling I chose and it's not necessary.